# Java Eclipse Theme.AppCompat error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets2.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why am I getting an error that says I need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendent) with this activity? I am trying to run this on API 19.

Comment: You can add an ActionBar to your activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending  android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity for your activity and setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme.

Comment: @betorcs how do I do this? Is it in one of the Android Manifest tabs or do I code this in the MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <activity
        android:name="net.androidbootcamp.concerttickets2.MainActivity" <-- If this guy extends ActionBarCompat -->
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" <!-- Then, android:theme must extends Theme.AppCompat -->
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If you don't need actionBar (NoTitleBar), just change your class to use `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { // Instead of extends ActionBarCompat

}
```

But if you want use ActionBarCompat, so create an custom theme extending Theme.AppCompat

eg.:

```
public class MyActivityWithActionBarCompat extends ActionBarActivity {


}
```

**/res/values/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```

**manifest**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivityWithActionBarCompat"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It seems the copy paste solution always beats telling people what the problem is and then asking them to RTFM...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a theme which extends from `Theme.AppCompat`. This is a requirement when using the `AppCompat` library.

More info on styling your ActionBar with AppCompat themes [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes).

Comment: how do you know if a theme extends from Theme.AppCompat? And also is it a requirement to use AppCompat, what does it do?

Comment: Usually the dev is the one defining the `Theme`, and you use one of the `AppCompat` themes as its parent. (`parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`)